# Как создать разделители горизонтального меню на CSS

Tags: css, меню

Помогите пожалуйста сделать такие разделители на CSS :

[image: разделители меню]

Comment: с помощью псевдоэлементов `:before` и `:after`, у которых есть свойство `content`. В это свойство и пишем данный символ "вертикальное многоточие".
Вот так
`content: '\e22EE';`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/2kxk80m7/

Comment: @Umer, пожалуйста, оформите ваш комментарий как ответ.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возьмем немного измененное решение г-на soledar10.
Собственно говоря, сделано через псевдоэлемент `:before`

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul{
  text-align: center;
  background: #555;
  
}
ul > li{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
ul > li a{
  display: block;
  padding: 18px 30px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
}
ul > li a:before{
  content: '⋮';
  position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 0;      
  width: 1px;
  height: 16px;
  margin-top: -8px;
}
ul > li:first-child a:before{
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li><a href="#">menu 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">menu 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">menu 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">menu 4</a></li>
</ul>
```